# Place div below other div

Tags: css, html, position, size

I am making my first layout by using full div elements but I have encountered a problem.
I have a div with fixed position, and auto height(will expand based on content) but I can't seem to be able to place another div below it. How can the div below automatically be positioned depending on the height of the div above?

These divs will be included inside a wrapper div that places them on the center of the screen.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kfbjd/ (note that the first div has a top value so the bottom div overrides it)
Fixed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfbjd/14/

```
<div id="main">
<div id="maintext">MAIN</div>

</div>

<div id="about">
<div id="maintext">ABOUT</div>

</div>

<style type="text/css">
#main{
    background-color:#000;
    width:900px;
    top:129px;
    position:fixed;
}

#about{
    background-color:#000;
    width:900px;
    position:relative;
}
</style>
```

Thanks for your suggestions adding top:129px to #about fixed it. There is an issue though, although it appears correctly on the jsfiddle on my browser the text appears wrapped:

[image]

Comment: No you can't, that's what absolutely positioned means, it doesn't affect the regular flow. The alternative is to put both divs inside the same absolutely positione element

Comment: You will not want two separate divs with the same ID ("maintext").  The point of an ID is it is a unique identifier.

Comment: Perhaps you could make a stripped down www.jsfiddle.net demonstrating your issue. It's easier for people to help with a specific issue if the can 'fiddle' with the code.

Comment: @zefs You need to explain yourself better. Start with this http://jsfiddle.net/rmah5/

Comment: Added jsfiddle on first post

Comment: I modified your jsfiddle and updated my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move your #about inside #main, it will correctly position itself http://jsfiddle.net/kfbjd/3/

If you can't do that, you can just add

```
top:129px;
```

To the #about div (matching what you already gave to #main). http://jsfiddle.net/kfbjd/5/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions this fixed it. There is an issue though, although it appears correctly on the jsfiddle on my browser the text appears wrapped: http://imageshack.us/a/img560/4449/69214628.jpg

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  Here it is, using your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfbjd/7/

As someone else commented, fixed or absolute position will remove it from the flow of the page, so you will not be able to have other divs position themselves around it.  If you did position relative and then used the css 'display: block' style, it might get you closer to what you are looking for.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Updating to contain full-text of solution from JSFiddle, including horizontal centering, for posterity:

```
<style>
#main{
    background-color:#000;
    width:900px;
    margin-top:149px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
    opacity:0.9;
    z-index:2;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;    
}

.maintext{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#6b6b6b;
    padding:25px;
    text-align:left;
    -webkit-touch-callout: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;    
}

#about{
    background-color:#000;
    width:900px;
    /*height:450px;    */
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;
    opacity:0.9;
    z-index:2;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;    
}
</style>

<div id="main">
<div class="maintext">Welcome to my personal portfolio. Here you can find projects I have worked on, and hire me for freelance work. If you like my work and want to hire me for projects please check out my software skills <a href="about.html">here</a> and <a href="contact.html">contact</a> me to discuss about projects.Welcome to my personal portfolio.
<div style="text-align:center;"><br/><img src="images/green.png" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:3px;"/>Available for freelance work</div></div>

</div>

<div id="about">
<div class="maintext">ABOUT TEXT</div>
​
```

Comment: You still need to guess the size of the div on top so you can offset the affected divs

Comment: If your requirement is also that the text is centered horizontally, add :  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;  to both of the main and about styles.

Comment: @JuanMendes: What do you mean??

Comment: In fairness, Tom, he was responding to the state of my answer when all I had recommended was the block layout.  The answer has now been refined and I believe completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the 'about' div to be at the bottom of the fixed position 'main' div and you know the height of the "about" div you can do something like this:

```
<style>
    #main{
    background-color:#000;
    width:900px;
    top:129px;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0px 0px 100px 0px;
}

#about{
    background-color:#ff0000;
    width:900px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
height:100px;
}
</style>

<div id="main">
    <div id="maintext">MAIN</div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <div id="about">
    <div id="maintext">ABOUT</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The padding on the bottom of "main" will allow the space for the "about" div to appear at the bottom(otherwise it will overlap stuff at the bottom of "main" div). I just put 100pixels as an example height for the "about" div.